# Удалить объект из списка

Tags: java, list

У меня есть список и объект, но я не знаю его порядковый номер, как я могу его удалить из списка?

```
private List<Product> products;

public void deleteProduct(Object product) {
    products.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [одной из перегрузок функции `remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), которая принимает объект.

```
private List<Product> products;

public void deleteProduct(Object product) {
    products.remove(product);
}
```

Comment: пишет, что нужно поменять object на string

Comment: Именно на `String`, не на `Product`? Было бы здорово увидеть код и полный текст ошибки.

Comment: private List products;

Comment: public void deleteProduct(Object product){
  products.remove(product);;
 }

Comment: и просит поменять product на String

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, привести **полный** текст ошибки? [У меня, например, компилятор не просит ничего поменять](http://ideone.com/CgQBgc)

Comment: у меня несколько классов текста

Comment: Если честно, по одной фразе `просит поменять product на String` совершенно не понятно, в чём может быть проблема. На [ideone](http://ideone.com/CgQBgc) решение работает. Мне кажется, что вам стоит попробовать создать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)